# How to handle questions closed as duplicates, when the duplicate has been closed and deleted?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question

I came across [How should I dispose of all of this old hardware?](https://superuser.com/q/312470/53590), which was posted in July 2011 and closed after about an hour and a half, with two answers posted.

That question is closed as a duplicate of [What is the best way to dispose of non-working computer equipment?](https://superuser.com/q/41623/53590), which:

- Was posted in September 2009
- Has 8 answers
- Was closed in July 2014
- Was deleted by a moderator a day and half after it was closed

This leaves the original question hanging in the air, and no way for users with less than 10k rep to see the majority of answers.

How do we handle these situations? Would it perhaps be better to undelete the linked-as-duplicate-of question, and instead lock it as "historical interest"?

Comment: That question should probably be deleted as well.